# How to create pages / tabs in table - HTML5 / angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, rest

I am getting approx. 500 records from REST response. I am showing them in a table(angular). I want to create some customization giving user a choice to show 10 /20/30... records per page and then provide previous and next button to navigate between the pages.

How to do it? or what is it called?

Thanks

Comment: Might as well just use ng-table - http://ng-table.com

Answer (score 0):

Angualr Datatables would be the best choice: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome. It can give user the choice to show any number of records per page.